# Linux Mint 21 - ctrl + 5 not sending any input and discarding xmodmap changes

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

Yesterday, I updated Linux Mint to version 21. With that update, one small but for me huge issue creeped into the install.

I often play FFXIV on this computer, and I have keybinds with a MMO mouse, using the number keys plus either shift or ctrl to modify the command. I already had the problem before, that one of the keys of the mmo mouse didnt correctly register with ffxiv, forcing me to use xmodmap to overwrite the keybind with something else every time I start the game.

After updating to Linux Mint 21, pressing ctrl + 5 does not send any data to the game anymore, and furthermore all adjustments to my keybinds I make with xmodmap are discarded.
It does happen outside of the game as well, this is just how I found the issue and why its a problem for me. It basically stops me from using 4 of my keybinds that I need.

I first thought its simply a keyboard shortcut in the keyboard settings, but I could not find anything that uses ctrl + 5. This only started happening with the upgrade to Linux Mint 21. Ctrl + 5 does not register with any program anymore and furthermore deletes all my xmodmap adjustments.

Anyone knows anything about this and can help?

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar problem in my Asus notebook. The instant key did not work after the upgrade from LM 20.3 to 21. I solved this by resetting the keybindings in the keyboard menu, and then set the desired behavior to the instant key.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Your answer is a bit terse and could be improved by explaining the issue, i.e., the underlying cause of the problem and why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question.